# Change music in lockscreen

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, lockscreen

Is it possible for my app to skip or pause the music that is currently being played while the device (iPhone) is locked (for example after a given preset time)?

Answer (score 0):

To play some music

```
func playSpawnedDot() {
    var alertSound: NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("spawnDot", ofType: "mp3")!)!
    var error:NSError?
    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertSound, error: &error)
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()

    if volumeBool {
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

And play while app is in background too add this

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient, error: nil)
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)
```

To stop the music after n seconds do have a look in background modes
[Background modes IOS](https://www.raywenderlich.com/143128/background-modes-tutorial-getting-started)